# Fixed table columns implementation

Tags: html, css

*I moved this question here from Code Review as it was found off-topic there*

I'm trying to implement fixed table columns. I've found a quite easy pure CSS implementation, which I haven't seen before. [Here you can check out](https://jsfiddle.net/foLbpfk2/) the little fiddle which fixes the first column. I've tested it only in latest IE and Chrome yet.

As I'm not an expert when it comes to deep browser rendering and browser compatibility, I have two main questions:

1. **Why is it actually working?** Sounds weird but I really don't understand. According to my best knowledge, using `absolute` positioning *should not* fix it relatively to the scrolling parent, but relatively to it's offset parent, which is the `tr` element. So actually I was surprised that it works.
2. **Is it safe?** Should it work in different and probably older browsers too? It sounds too good to be true.

Besides I would like to hear your thoughts and tips on this one and other possible solutions. What I would like to avoid is to split the `table` into two and use overlapping to mimic fixed columns (like for example many datatable libraries do).

**UPDATE**

Interestingly it seems like the `relative` positioning is not even needed on the `tr` elements to work properly. Now I'm completely confused about why and how it's working.

Comment: I don't fully understand why you are trying to do it this way. 

Tables are primitive structures - if you give them a fixed width they will be that width and won't resize flexibly. Similarly table-cells with fixed width (unless you disrupt them with oversize images etc).

Notions of relative / absolute as applied to rows / columns make no  sense in the context of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TR and position: relative**

Absolute positioned elements are taken out of the flow. By giving the tbody a padding, some space is created to show the first column in.

It works, because the width of the first column and that padding are fixed (to 150px).

Then there is this weird rule:

```
table > tbody > tr {
  position: relative;
}
```

Let's call it ***Rule R*** from now on. ;-)

Your remark about the offset parent, which is the `tr`, sounds about right. 
However, [according to the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position), the behaviour of `position: relative` on table rows is 'undefined', so that might be a problem.

In Chrome it looks like the whole rule is ignored, and if I remove *Rule R*, the fiddle still works the same.

So that 'explains' why it works. *Rule R* would break it, but it doesn't because it is simply ignored (by Chrome at least).

**Why the `top` works**

Since there are no positioned elements, the cells responds to the document body, and that explains why it doesn't move with the div's contents.

The absolute positioning would leave the element at its original (static) position, [also according to standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width). Through CSS (only) the `left` is changed to 0.

So, the element is positioned on the left side of the body (looking 'fixed') at the top it would have had, if it had been in the flow, so that's its normal top position within the `tr`. No weirdness there.

FWIW, see [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foLbpfk2/1/) that has some content, showing that the entire div contents are moving, but not the first column, nor the contents of the body outside of `.container`.

**Risk**

So is there is risk? 
I think theoretically not, although this is one of those weird implementation that could just trigger some edge case bug in some browsers. It seems to work fine, and if you remove *Rule R* is seems to follow standards too.

**Additional remarks**
You don't need to specify any width for the table. You could simply let it asjust to the width it needs. The only thing that needs to have a fixed width is the first column. 
So, a bit stripped down, here is [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foLbpfk2/2/).

Comment: Ahh I see now, thank you. I slapped myself after reading your answer. Actually I got mislead by jsfiddle itself, as I didn't realize that there is an `iframe` so the `body` is visually same as the container `div`. Now I completely understand what's happening of course. So it turned out that this technique is not usable in most real-world cases..

Comment: The fixed `table-layout` and the fixed widths are given because this is grabbed out from a progressing data grid implementation which will allow column resizing.

Comment: Why is it not useable? I think you could add an extra container div around the whole snippet and add ’ position: relative ’ to it.

Comment: Hm.. you might be right, I'm now at this point, and it seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/foLbpfk2/3/ thank you for the ideas so far. It seems like there are no problems which could not be solved with an "extra wrapper" div :)